# Xcode textLabel property of UITableViewCell not wrapping the text properly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, word-wrap

I am facing problems with `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` for the text assigned to the label text of a `UITableViewCell` and the cell is created during run time for that `UITableView`.. My problem is for some text it is getting wrapped and moved to next line whereas for some text it is not getting wrapped. The text is getting cut off at the ends . I am setting the text as shown in the below code.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 10;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.text = MyString;
```

For example the text "moral vacuum had been so successfully sucked clean of every molecule of real qualm or scruple" is being displayed as "moral vacuum had been so successfully sucked clean of every molecule of real qualm". The last two words "or scruple" is getting cut off and not being word wrapped.

For the other text "love is our sympathy with organic life, the touchingly lustful embrace of what is destined to decay", it is properly word wrapped and moved to the next line.

Can you please suggest what settings needs to be made to the `UITableViewCell` such that the `Word Wrapping` functions for all the text accordingly?

Comment: I just tested with programatically registered and add view cell with your code snapshot. All works well with Xcode 11.2 + several iPhone simulators of different form factor. So I assume the issue is not in the provided code.

Comment: Issue is getting occurred only in iPad devices and the font size being set to 22.0 f

Comment: Nope, not reproducible - all works fine, with any font size with any iPad.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are testing with?

Answer (score 0):

Below is complete test module. Storyboard contains only TableViewController with class set to `MyTableController`.

```c
@import UIKit;

@interface MyTableController : UITableViewController
@end

@interface MyTableController ()
@end

@interface MyCell: UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation MyCell
@end

@implementation MyTableController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:MyCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // UITableViewCell *cell = UITableViewCell.new; // << tested also with this

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]; // << tested also with different font sizes
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 10; // << tested also with 0 value for dynamic height
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"moral vacuum had been so successfully sucked clean of every molecule of real qualm or scruple";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

[image: demo]

Comment: The code is same as the code you written but still i am getting issue.. Even i am having cell.accessoryType being set to UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailsDisclosureButton. Is this causing the text to cut off ? I tried removing this line of code & verified but still the text is getting cut off

Comment: After making changes as per your code, the accessorytype for the cell is missing. It is not being shown.

Comment: Review settings in storyboard for table, because I did not change anything there after creation.

Comment: Are you able to set the accessory type to the cell and display it

Comment: Can you please tell me on which iPad simulator you have tested this?